# Plotting a variable number of series and data forecasts onto subplots, including axis labels, formatting and line colours

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm writing a program which gets data and then uses time series forecasting to predict data values for the next, say, 300 data points.

However, only data which fulfills a certain condition will be plotted, so there is no defined number of subplots for the add_subplot() method. I'm aware of the plot.subplots() function, but something such as

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
```

implies that two graphs will definitely be plotted and I need to change the specific amount, like with a parameter.

Here is a simplified version of the current code which results in each plot being in separate windows:

```
fig = plt.figure()  # creates a figure instance for the final graph output

plots = 1  # indicates the total number of plots to plot, starting from 1
           # passed as a parameter to the add_subplot() function

for data in dataSet:
    forecast(data, fig, plots)

plt.figure(fig.number)

plt.show()
```

And the function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tick
from pandas import Series
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing

def forecast(data, superFigure, plotNumber):

    index = range(0, len(data))

    plotData = Series(data, index)

    # fit the data values into a specific model:
    modelFit = ExponentialSmoothing(plotData, trend="add").fit()

    # forecast for the next 300 points:
    modelForecast = modelFit.forecast(300)

    if [condition]:

        # plot the original data points:
        points = plotData.plot(marker='x', color='black', label='Base Data')
        points.set_xlim(0, len(data) + 300)

        # plot the forecast in a different colour:
        modelForecast.plot(marker='x', ax=points, color='blue', label='Forecasted Data')

        plt.title("Plot Title")
        plt.xlabel("X Axis")
        plt.ylabel("Y Axis")

        # format the axes, adding thousand separator
        points.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(
            tick.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
        points.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(
            tick.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))

        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
```

This produces multiple graphs such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHaq4.jpg) (actual labels have been cut out).

Unfortunately you have to close each graph before viewing the next one, and I want every graph to be visible on one page.

I tried changing the code within the "if [condition]" to:

```
if [condition]:

    points = plotData.plot(marker='x', color='black', label='Base Data')
    modelForecast.plot(marker='x', ax=points, color='blue', label='Forecasted Data')

    dataLine = plt.gca().get_lines()[0]
    forecastLine = plt.gca().get_lines()[1]

    #  put all x and y values into single lists by concatenating them
    totalXData = [*dataLine.get_xdata(), *forecastLine.get_xdata()]
    totalYData = [*dataLine.get_ydata(), *forecastLine.get_ydata()]

    subset = superFigure.add_subplot(10, 10, plotNumber)

    for i in range(0, len(totalXData)):
        subset.plot(totalXData[i], totalYData[i])

    plotNumber += 1
```

These changes produce [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms6ZL.jpg) exact graph which seems to have the other graphs squished in the top-left corner, and I get "MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance" warnings.

If I change "superFigure.add_subplot(10, 10, plotNumber)" to "superFigure.add_subplot(20, 20, plotNumber)" I also get "UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. tight_layout cannot make axes width small enough to accommodate all axes decorations".

I then tried to change it to:

```
if [condition]:

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    plotData.plot(marker='x', ax=ax, color='black', label='Base Data')
    modelForecast.plot(marker='x', ax=ax, color='blue', label='Forecasted Data')

    ax.set([...])
    ax.legend()

    plt.show()
```

which doesn't produce the desired output assumedly because it recreates the figure on each call of forecast(), unless a figure window can contain multiple figures.

I also sometimes get the following warning:

> RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created
>   through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained
>   until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory.
>
> - fig, ax = plt.subplots()

How can I create subplots which include all the formatting and are displayed in one window all together?

Comment: To plot a dataframe to an axes `ax`, use `df.plot(..., ax=ax)`.

Comment: I tried setting ax=ax but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Of course `ax` should be the subplot you want to use.